# How to list subfolders matching PATTERN in PowerShell?

Tags: grep, powershell-2.0

My script is used to find all subfolders with criteria like name matching under the root folder:

```
$Allsubfolders= gci c:\Root -recurse | Group-Object directoryname | select name
    foreach ($folder in $Allsubfolders) {
    if (($folder.name) -like "*NY*"){
        $list = @(  
            @{source = "$($folder.name)"; dest=c:\dest}     
        )
}
```

The problem I have with my script is that I cannot grep all folders matching NY, I can only grep one of them. It seems like it stop on the first occurrence. How can I resolve this?

Comment: use `sed` instead of `grep`.  Use `sed /PATTERN/!d`, which will delete all  occurrences that do not match `PATTERN` leaving ***all*** of the instances which do.  If you do not have access to `sed` in your environment, then consider using `perl` as a stand-in for `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something list this?

```
$Allsubfolders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'NY'
```